# How do I Limit Location of Object A from Object B, but use World Space transform so that the Limit Location is not affected by B's rotation?

Tags: objects, transforms, constraints

I'm using the *Limit Location* constraint to make Object A's location be constrained within bounds from Object B's.

The problem is that when Object B is rotated using the *Limit Rotation* constraint, Object A's *Limit Location* axes become Object B's transformed space:

[image]

Is there a way to keep Object A's *Limit Location* axes tacked to World Space, but still follow Object B?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on Reddit suggested to use the Copy Location constraint and it worked like a charm!

This is what i did:

1. Add Limit Location constraint to world axis
2. Add Copy Location constraint. NOTE: I had to check the use_offset checkbox.